# Incorrect output of fork

Tags: c, fork

Consider the output of the below program:

```
int main()
{
    int ret;
    ret=fork();
    ret=fork();
    ret=fork();
    ret=fork();

    if(!ret)
            printf("one\n");
    else
            printf("two\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the output as:

```
two
one
two
two
```

http://ideone.com/omgKm

AFAIT, the output should be `8 times one` & `8 times two`.

**Where are the rest `one's` & `two's`?**

Comment: This is possibly an artifact of the way ideone works.  Running locally, I get the "expected" output.

Comment: @Oli: There's still something goofy about this code. The `ret` is only checked at the end.

Comment: Tested on Mac OS X 10.7.4, I get more or less the expected output.  Since you perpetually overwrite `ret`, you lose any information about which `fork()` failed, but maybe one or more of them did fail.

Comment: @0A0D: Indeed. But assuming none of the forks failed, there should be a total of 8 calls to the final fork, resulting in 16 final values of ret.

Comment: @0A0D: The check at the end means that half of the final wave of 16 processes will be parents with `ret != 0` and half will be children with `ret == 0`.  It is odd, but it works OK.

Comment: He's _never_ checking if any of the fork()s failed - fork() returns -1 on failure.  I tested and get the expected output - so the way forward is to actually check the return code of each fork().

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I see 6 fork failures, 4 successful forks with 1 parent - assuming that a child can't fork.

Comment: My best guess is that ideone does not allow you to create more than four processes -- two forks succeed, the remainder fail.  However, it is surprising that you got even one `one` in the output, and is an argument against this hypothesis.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: Map it out on paper. Am I correct that a child process can't fork? I can't seem to find any documentation to say that it can.

Comment: @0A0D: A child process can definitely fork.

Comment: @0A0D: Every process in Unix is a child process of the original PID = 1 (which is hand-crafted differently from every other process), or of one of its children.  Your login shell is a child process; it runs child processes, ...

Comment: I'm voting to close as "too localized".  My belief is we're just seeing an artifact of the way ideone.com collects its output.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: it is an artefact of ideone; see my demo code with a `wait()` loop at http://ideone.com/zFoLn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this alternative code which tracks what goes on somewhat better:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ret1 = fork();
    int ret2 = fork();
    int ret3 = fork();
    int ret4 = fork();

    if (ret4 == 0)
        printf("one: (%d: %d, %d, %d, %d)\n", (int)getpid(), ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4);
    else
        printf("two: (%d: %d, %d, %d, %d)\n", (int)getpid(), ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4);
    return 0;
}
```

Show us the output from this variation and we can see what worked and what failed.

---

After seeing the alternative output, I got this on my Mac (where `Isis JL:` is my prompt and `rmk` is an alternative implementation of `make`):

```
Isis JL: rmk fb && ./fb
    /usr/bin/gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra fb.c -o fb  
two: (38068: 38069, 38070, 38071, 38072)
one: (38072: 38069, 38070, 38071, 0)
two: (38071: 38069, 38070, 0, 38075)
two: (38070: 38069, 0, 38074, 38077)
two: (38073: 0, 0, 38078, 38079)
two: (38069: 0, 38073, 38076, 38080)
one: (38075: 38069, 38070, 0, 0)
one: (38077: 38069, 0, 38074, 0)
Isis JL: two: (38074: 38069, 0, 0, 38081)
two: (38078: 0, 0, 0, 38082)
one: (38079: 0, 0, 38078, 0)
one: (38081: 38069, 0, 0, 0)
two: (38076: 0, 38073, 0, 38083)
one: (38080: 0, 38073, 38076, 0)
one: (38083: 0, 38073, 0, 0)
one: (38082: 0, 0, 0, 0)

Isis JL:
```

Note the interleaved prompt — the blank line at the end is where I hit return after the output completed.

#### Hypothesis:

The output on ideone is not captured after the initial process stops.

Try this alternative, which waits for children to die before exiting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ret1 = fork();
    int ret2 = fork();
    int ret3 = fork();
    int ret4 = fork();

    if (ret4 == 0)
        printf("one: (%d: %d, %d, %d, %d)\n", (int)getpid(), ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4);
    else
        printf("two: (%d: %d, %d, %d, %d)\n", (int)getpid(), ret1, ret2, ret3, ret4);
    while (wait(0) > 0)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

Output on Mac, once more:

```
Isis JL: rmk fb && ./fb
    /usr/bin/gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra fb.c -o fb  
two: (38111: 38112, 38113, 38114, 38115)
one: (38115: 38112, 38113, 38114, 0)
two: (38114: 38112, 38113, 0, 38119)
two: (38113: 38112, 0, 38117, 38121)
two: (38117: 38112, 0, 0, 38123)
one: (38119: 38112, 38113, 0, 0)
two: (38118: 0, 38116, 0, 38124)
one: (38121: 38112, 0, 38117, 0)
one: (38125: 0, 0, 38122, 0)
two: (38116: 0, 0, 38122, 38125)
two: (38122: 0, 0, 0, 38126)
two: (38112: 0, 38116, 38118, 38120)
one: (38120: 0, 38116, 38118, 0)
one: (38123: 38112, 0, 0, 0)
one: (38124: 0, 38116, 0, 0)
one: (38126: 0, 0, 0, 0)
Isis JL:
```

---

#### Hypothesis Proven

To the extent you can prove anything...  http://ideone.com/zFoLn ...

This shows all 16 lines of output.  The problem must have been 'premature termination'.

Comment: @KurzedMetal: That's curious, but it's possible we're just debugging ideone.com here; who knows how it collects stdout.  Can you reproduce this in a local environment?